# Outlook Edit Message

Tags: ms-office

I am using the new outlook (Blue Icon) for OSX with a microsoft-online subscription account. I noticed there is an option called "Edit Message" when viewing an email in the sent-items.

[image]

i was under the impression this option will allow me to change an email after it was sent, as long as the recipient was in the same domain (exchange server)

Is my assumption correct? I am not able to find any reference regarding this feature in help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any message can be edited. This does not affect the message for anyone else, it simply lets you edit the message for yourself.

Comment: can you tell me what would be a good use of such a feature?

Comment: @DevZer0 E.g. if someone emailed me without a subject, I could edit the message to add my own so I could find it later.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer :) i find it rather a strange feature and people could miss-use it by adding or removing content and making false claims. the use-case you mentioned can be achieved through some tag/label system. This is just my feeling. :-)